# How to transform a prefetch_related query into dataframe using panda

Tags: django, pandas

I would simply like to transform a prefetch_related query into a Panda dataframe with all the information from the two models below. This should be very simple but somehow nothing works. I get a 'Capture_set is not defined' with the code below.
Any idea ?

```
class Capture(models.Model):
  species_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  total_capture = models.IntegerField()



class Species(models.Model):
  species_name = models.ForeignKey(Capture, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
  length = models.IntegerField()
  weight = models.IntegerField()


data = pd.DataFrame(list(Species.objects.all().prefetch_related(Capture_set)))
```

Comment: It should read dataframe, not database. sorry.

Comment: `Capture_set is not defined` sounds like you haven't defined a variable `Capture_set`...and it doesn't look like such a definition is in the code you posted.  What do you expect `Capture_set` to contain and where do you define it?

Comment: I thought that was how you were supposed to use prefetch_related based on other examples (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176430/django-does-prefetch-related-follow-reverse-relationship-lookup). But even with simply capture instead of capture_set I still an error (type object 'Capture' has no attribute 'split')

Answer (score 1):

I know is not the way you were looking for, but you can achieve this with values(). Let's suppose your [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) is "captures"

```
import pandas


query = Species.objects.all().values('captures__pk', 'captures__species_name',
                                     'captures__total_capture', 'pk', 'length',
                                     'weight')
data = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(query)
```